# Convert NOT EXISTS Query to Laravel Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have an eloquent model called `Skill` that is a hierarchical element using a [closure table](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-closure-tables/) implementation.

As part of my application I want to be able to get all leaves with where `isCategory = false`. I can achieve this using the following 'raw' query in mysql:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 56574730041811ea9fcb0800279ee528.skills a
WHERE 
a.isCategory <> true AND
NOT EXISTS(SELECT uuid, parent_uuid, isCategory
              FROM   56574730041811ea9fcb0800279ee528.skills b
              WHERE  b.parent_uuid <> 'null' AND
                     b.parent_uuid = a.uuid 
             );
```

I want to convert this to a Laravel query builder query but I am not sure how to implement the `b.parent_uuid = a.uuid` clause. For example:

```
Skill::where('isCategory', false)
     ->whereNotExists(function($query) {
         $query->select('uuid', 'parent_uuid')
               ->whereNotNull('parent_uuid')
               ->where('parent_uuid', '=', <How to reference the outer query?>)
        });
```

How do I successfully convert this query?

Comment: is this table's name: `56574730041811ea9fcb0800279ee528.skills`?

Comment: No the table name is skills, the UUID is the database name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `->from()` inside the `whereNotExists` method, and `whereColumn` to check two fields are same:

```
Skill::where('isCategory', false)
     ->whereNotExists(function($query) {
         $query->select('uuid', 'parent_uuid', 'isCategory')
               ->from('skills AS b')
               ->whereNotNull('b.parent_uuid')
               ->whereColumn('b.parent_uuid', 'skills.uuid')
        });
```